# Prevent jekyll for loop from skipping future posts

Tags: jekyll

I have a jekyll website with a blog section that has this:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  ... display post ...
{% endfor %}
```

This blog section correctly skips posts that are dated in the future.

In another part of my website I want to be able list posts that have a specific "Event" tag, regardless of the date of the post (so even posts in the future should be shown). I have something like this for now:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.tag contains "Event" %}
    ... display post ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However this loop skips the posts that have a date in the future. How can I prevent this (only for this loop)? Solutions like setting `published: true` would not work because the blog section would start showing those posts as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `future` option is a build configuration option. This means you will have to set it to `true`, otherwise future posts are skipped from the `site.posts` collection during build.

Here's a workaround:

After you have set `future: true` in the `_config.yml` file, in your blog section, filter the posts like this:

```
{% assign filtered_posts = site.posts | where_exp: "post", "post.date <= site.time" %}
{% assign sorted_posts = filtered_posts | sort: 'post.date' %}
     
{% for post in sorted_posts %}
  ... display post ...
{% endfor %}
```

In your other section, you should then be able to list all posts with the `Event` tag including the future ones using the second code block in your question above.